# Physical difference between $\nabla^\bot\cdot u=0$, and $\nabla\cdot u^\bot=0$ and the existence of a scalar potential

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vector-analysis

If there exists a $2D$ vector field $u=u(x)=(u_1,u_2)$ such that $\nabla\cdot u=0$ is it equivalent to saying following?

$$\nabla\cdot u=?(\nabla\cdot u)^\bot=\nabla^\bot\cdot u^\bot=\nabla\times u^\bot=0$$

1. It is very easy to show that each part is identically zero but I am unsure if just because they are each zero, whether that makes them equivalent statements.

$$\nabla\cdot u=(\partial_1,\partial_2)\cdot(u_1,u_2)=\partial_1u_1+\partial_2u_2\equiv0$$
$$\nabla^\bot\cdot u^\bot=(\partial_2,-\partial_1)\cdot(u_2,-u_1)=\partial_2u_2+\partial_1u_1=\nabla\cdot u$$
$$\nabla\times u^\bot=\begin{vmatrix}e_1 & e_2 & e_3 \\\partial_1 & \partial_2 & 0 \\u_2 & -u_1 & 0 \\ \end{vmatrix}=(-\partial_1u_1-\partial_2u_2)e_3=-(\nabla\cdot u)e_3$$

2. Since $\nabla\times u^\bot=0$ that means there must exist a potential $\phi$ such that $u^\bot=\nabla \phi$. Is this equivalent to saying $u=\nabla^\bot \phi$?

Comment: Since $\nabla\cdot u$ is a scalar, I don't think $\left(\nabla\cdot u\right)^\bot$ is meaningful? But you have shown that $\nabla\cdot u=0$ implies $\nabla^\bot\cdot u^\bot=0$, so that is correct. For 2), try writing out the components of both equations.

Comment: @David Thank you, I'm just trying to understand what $\nabla^\bot\cdot u$ and $\nabla\cdot u^\bot$ actually mean. Do you know if $\nabla^\bot$ is referred to as the skew gradient or something else? I cannot find anything specific. Also, what does it mean to raise $\nabla$ or a vector to $\bot$?

Comment: For a vector $\vec v$, $\vec v^\bot$ is a vector perpendicular to $\vec v$. I don't know the physical interpretation of $\nabla^\bot$. I don't think $\vec v^\bot$ is particularly meaningful because it's just a simple transformation of the velocity vector.